# Understanding turtle circle, and arc in "Think Python"

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

In the interface design section in "Think Python" I need help understanding the approach to the circle and arc functions, like this:

```
import turtle
import polygon
bob = turtle.Turtle()

print(bob)

def polygon(t, n, length):

    angle = 360 / n
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(angle)
```

And after that, the book introduces another approach to drawing a circle by using a polygon function:

```
def circle(t, r):

    circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
    n = int(circumference / 3 ) + 1
    length = circumference / n
    polygon(t, n, length)
```

**What I don't understand:**

- I have no idea why they define `circumference` to draw circle and how it works to draw a circle.
- If I call the function like `circle(bob, 100)` then it only draws a fraction of circle not the whole circle.
- I don't understand why `n` is needed, and how that procedure can make a circle.

Answer (score 5):

> I have no idea why they define circumference to draw circle and how it
>   take a work to draw a circle

One way we can visualize a circle is by drawing a polygon with the number of sides equal to the (integer) circumference of the circle with each side being 1 in length.  For a circle of radius = 100, that would be:

```
polygon(bob, 628, 1)  # 628 = 2 * PI * 100
```

which draws a nice, but slow circle:

[image]

We can speed this up by using a rougher approximation.  The `circle()` function above arbitrarily divides the number of sides the polygon will have by 3 but then increases the length of each side by 3:

```
polygon(bob, 209, 3)
```

This is just a sightly rougher circle but draws more quickly:

[image]

> If I call the function like circle(bob, 100) then it only draws a
>   fraction of circle not the whole circle.

I believe you're mixing up the `circle()` function defined above with the `circle()` method that comes with turtle.  It was confusing of the author to reuse the "circle" name this way.  The second argument to the turtle `circle()` method is an *extent*:

> extent - an angle - determines which part of the
>       circle is drawn. If extent is not given, draw the entire circle.
>       If extent is not a full circle, one endpoint of the arc is the
>       current pen position.

So the "Think Python" function call:

```
circle(bob, 100)
```

draws a circle of radius 100:

[image]

The turtle method:

```
bob.circle(100, 90)
```

draws an *arc* (1/4 circle) based on a radius of 100:

[image]

> I don't understand why n is needed, and how that procedure can make a
>   circle.

The `n` is the number of sides on the polygon that approximates a circle:

```
n = int(circumference / 3 ) + 1
length = circumference / n
polygon(t, n, length)
```

Starting with a radius of 100, if we replace the '3' above with `1`, we'd get a polygon with more (629) sides:

```
n = int(circumference / 1) + 1  # n = 629
length = circumference / n  # length = 0.9989
```

or roughly:

```
polygon(t, 628, 1)
```

Illustrated above.  But if we replace '3' with '27', we'd get a circle approximated by a polygon of 24 sides:

```
n = int(circumference / 27 ) + 1  # n = 24
length = circumference / n  # length = 26.1799
```

[image]

The orignal '3' value should have been an additional argument -- in the `turtle.circle()` method, it's roughly equivalent to the *steps* argument:

> As the circle is approximated by an inscribed regular polygon,
>       steps determines the number of steps to use. If not given,
>       it will be calculated automatically. May be used to draw regular
>       polygons.

```
bob.circle(100, steps=12)
```

[image]